# Debugging MonoMac apps using Mono Tools and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, monomac, mono-tools

If a MonoMac app has been compiled on MonoDevelop, can it be remotely debugged via [Mono-tools](http://mono-tools.com/Debug.aspx) (or anything else) on Visual Studio running on a Windows machine?

**Scenario**

Several library assemblies are compiled on Windows .NET and copied over to a Mac. Their symbols are then converted from .pdb to mono's .mdb format using pdb2mdb.

The final executable that references the libraries is compiled on MonoDevelop on a Mac. This produces the .app bundle that contains the plist, xibs and the referenced library assemblies.

This app can currently be run and debugged on Mac using MonoDevelop.

**Question**: Is there a way to remotely debug the app using Visual Studio?

**Research**

1. [Mono-tools](http://mono-tools.com/Debug.aspx) seems to be a good starting point, but it seems to require that the entire app be compiled in Visual Studio. This is not possible with a MonoMac app.
2. Looked for the sources for mono-tools but could not find any. Also could not find a third party solution for this scenario.